# Laravel BadMethodCallException not finding my model method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

For some reasons I getting error on downloadHistorys() relationship method OneToMany:
[image]
My models User and DumpDownloadHistory:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\DumpDownloadHistory;
use App\Models\Groups;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Model  {

    protected $fillable = ['email', 'full_name', 'name', 'mobile', 'phone', 'fax', 'downloadPrice', 'tokens', 'dailyDownloads', 'added_by', 'groups_id', 'status', 'user_about','admin_note', 'password', 'last_access', 'last_ip'];

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function downloadHistorys(){
        return $this->hasMany(DumpDownloadHistory::class);
    }

}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DumpDownloadHistory extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'dataset', 'user_ip', 'downloadCost'];

    protected $table = 'dump_download_histories';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

My models are placed in App\Models folder. I added my models instance to the controller. I getting an error when I try to call my methods. Any help will be helpful.

```
auth()->user()->downloadHistorys()->create([
                  'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                  'dataset' => $id,
                  'user_ip'=> request()->ip(),
                  'downloadCost' => auth()->user()->downloadPrice
                ]);
```

P.S. I not using a schema builder for the database. I have connected to an existing MySQL database.

**Edited**

config/auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Can you post config/auth.php  providers section. I think your authentication is connected to another Model ( App\User by default)

Comment: Added at the post config.auth code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

this section is wrong. If you want to use App\Models\User model as your authentication, change model to App\Models\User.

---

And change your App\Models\User model like this

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable {}
```

Comment: After editing this part, my code started to crash. Now I getting Call to undefined method App\Models\User::getAuthIdentifierName() error.

Comment: @DomantasŠlaičiūnas I edited my answer. Please check this out. You have to inherit laravel Auth\User model to use authentication